# How to generate text on mailItem's inline response for Office Web Add-in using JS

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin

we have an Outlook Add-in for generating automatic greetings. The add-in is for VSTO and used C#.

Now, we want the same for the Office Web version. I searched a lot on that but cannot find **how we can insert text inside the editable area(before signature) when a user composes new mail or reply/ReplyAll to a mail**. Can anybody please guide me through this?